# 'posts_per_page' => -1 not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to run a query through all the posts in the $arg but it is only working for 11 posts. I've tried many suggestions from forums but I can't get it to work.

what do I need to do?

```
function test_update_random_number()
{
    global $post;
    $args    = array (
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value LIKE "%Yes%" rand',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'meta_key'       => 'feature_in_search',
        'post_type'      => 'therapist',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    );
    $myposts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post();

            $value = get_field( "feature_in_search", $post_id );
            if ( strpos( $value, 'es' ) !== false ) {
                $random_value = rand( 1, 100 );
                update_field( "field_58aebd8e060c0", $random_value, $post_id );
            } else {
                $random_value2 = rand( 100, 600 );
                update_field( "field_58aebd8e060c0", $random_value2, $post_id );
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

Comment: I think You wrong param variable type`'posts_per_page' => '-1' // this param must be int` -- see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Comment: doesn't the documentation say -1 is an option?I tried a large number like posts_per_page' => 500. It doesn't work either.

Comment: Try with `'posts_per_page' => -1` also remove `meta_key` and `orderby` maybe You worng in this parameters.

Comment: removing meta_key and orderby makes it work but why doesn't it work with the meta_key? I need that clause?

Comment: Make `orderby => rand` and for `meta_value` select use `meta_query` with `'compare' => 'LIKE'`

Answer (score 3):

Your problems is not with the `posts_per_page` parameter, but with the `orderby` parameter.

You have `'orderby' => 'meta_value LIKE "%Yes%" rand',` , which doesn't make much sense. Also, if you want to order randomly, ordering `ASC` or `DESC` doesn't make sense either... :)

Apparently you want to filter all the posts that have a meta_field "feature_in_search" with a value of "Yes", and randomly sorted. So you should do:

```
$args    = [
    'meta_key'       => 'feature_in_search',
    'meta_value'     => 'Yes',
    'post_type'      => 'therapist',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'rand'
];
```

If you really want to search for things that *contain* "Yes" (and use a "LIKE" search) you would need to construct a proper [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).